# Confused on using dropout in batch gradient descent with Q-learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am using PyTorch and adding dropout layers to my inner layers.

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
  #def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_action, n_hidden_layers=2, hidden_dim=8, drop=0.25):
  def __init__(self, console_file, n_inputs, n_action, layers_list, drop=0.25):
    super(MLP, self).__init__()
    print("Layers structure:")
    console_file.write("Layers structure:\n")
    print(f"inputs: {n_inputs}")
    console_file.write(f"inputs: {n_inputs}\n")
    self.layers = []
    for i, layer_size in enumerate(layers_list):
      if i == 0:
        layer = nn.Linear(n_inputs, layer_size)
      else:
        layer = nn.Linear(layers_list[i-1], layer_size)
      self.layers.append(layer)
      print(f"layer {i}: {layer_size}")
      console_file.write(f"layer {i}: {layer_size}\n")
      self.layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(0.1))
      if drop > 0.01:
        #self.layers.append(nn.Dropout(p = drop**(len(layers_list)-i)))
        self.layers.append(nn.Dropout(p = drop))
        #print(f"drop {i}: {drop**(len(layers_list)-i)}")
        print(f"drop {i}: {drop}")
        #console_file.write(f"drop {i}: {drop**(len(layers_list)-i)}\n")
        console_file.write(f"drop {i}: {drop}\n")
    # final layer
    self.layers.append(nn.Linear(layers_list[-1], n_action))
    self.layers = nn.Sequential(*self.layers)
    print(f"outputs: {n_action}")
    console_file.write(f"outputs: {n_action}\n")
    print("========= NN structure =========\n")
    console_file.write("========= NN structure =========\n\n")
  def forward(self, X):
    return self.layers(X)

  def save_weights(self, path):
    torch.save(self.state_dict(), path)

  def load_weights(self, path):
    self.load_state_dict(torch.load(path))
```

I am making sure to turn training on during training and eval mode outside training (removing the droput layers).

```
    self.model = he.MLP(console_file, state_size, self.action_size, DIMENSION, DROPOUT)
    if DROPOUT > 0.01:
      self.model.train()
...
      if DROPOUT > 0.01: # before testing
        agent.model.eval()
...
    if DROPOUT > 0.01: # after testing
      self.model.train()
```

My confusion is as to HOW if at all PyTorch keeps track of which neurons it disables between the forward propagation and the later time where a random batch of output-and-reward is selected and backpropagation is performed on a specific case originating in a forward propagation with specific neurons disabled.

```
def train_one_step(model, criterion, optimizer, inputs, targets):  
  # convert to tensors
  inputs = torch.from_numpy(inputs.astype(np.float32))
  targets = torch.from_numpy(targets.astype(np.float32))

  # zero the parameter gradients
  optimizer.zero_grad()

  # Forward pass
  outputs = model(inputs)
  loss = criterion(outputs, targets)

  # Backward and optimize
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()
```

inputs and targets are from random selection (batch over buffered history)

For me it makes sense to have the SAME neurons disabled between the forward and back propagation but since I can find nothing on the subject everything would suggest that the dropout will apply randomly and therefor nonsensically to me.
Either the forward and back propagations need to happen identically (and somehow PyTorch manages to remember by some markers, because I don't seem to pass any markers during batching) or I need to understand why they can be randomly different.

Comment: What do you mean by "random batch of output-and-reward is selected"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the problem, but let me try to explain how things work.

The `.train()` and `.eval()` calls only [change the `.training` flag](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/61914cb2fabea02016e5f3357051ae407dcc3070/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1579-L1597) to `True` or `False`.

The `Dropout` layer samples the noise during the forward pass. Here's an example of forward [implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/61914cb2fabea02016e5f3357051ae407dcc3070/aten/src/ATen/native/Dropout.cpp#L42-L70) (I removed the `if`s for the alpha and feature dropouts for readability):

```cpp
template<bool feature_dropout, bool alpha_dropout, bool inplace, typename T>
Ctype<inplace> _dropout_impl(T& input, double p, bool train) {
  TORCH_CHECK(p >= 0 && p <= 1, "dropout probability has to be between 0 and 1, but got ", p);
  if (p == 0 || !train || input.numel() == 0) {
    return input;
  }

  if (p == 1) {
    return multiply<inplace>(input, at::zeros({}, input.options()));
  }

  auto noise = at::empty_like(input, LEGACY_CONTIGUOUS_MEMORY_FORMAT);
  noise.bernoulli_(1 - p);
  noise.div_(1 - p);
  return multiply<inplace>(input, noise);
}
```

As you can see, if `!train` (i.e., `.eval()`), it will return the `input` as it is. Moreover, you could say that it "remembers" which neurons were disabled the same way it "remembers" what is the value of each active neuron. Notice that the dropout layer actually works as a mask of 0s and (scaled) 1s on the output of the previous layer. It does not actually mask the neurons, although in pratice the effect is equivalent, since the neurons that generated the outputs multiplied by 0 will get no gradient, and the rest will get properly scaled gradients (because of the `.div_(1-p)`).

Comment: thousands of forward passes get processed before backpropagation is performed, with the following happening based on batch selection (inputs,targets) where dropout layers were used before calculating specific outputs, rewards, based on specific inputs   # Forward pass
  outputs = model(inputs)
  loss = criterion(outputs, targets)

  # Backward and optimize
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()

Comment: so I don't see how it would remember what dropout was used for every case, especially since it calculates a new models(inputs), where targets contains rewards previously calculated; I suppose it is impossible to properly use dropout in this scenario

Comment: @Dan maybe you pasted the wrong snippet... what you mean by "thousands of forward passes get processed before backpropagation is performed"? In your code, the forward (`model(inputs)`) is immedially followed by a backward (`.backward()`) and gradient update (`.step()`).

Comment: targets are calculated and batched in advance, model(inputs) is re-calculated as a batch; as I see it, there will always be discrepancies between the system being trained and the older versions but more importantly, I see no reason to believe the same dropouts will be happening; note that inputs, targets and outputs are all multiple, according to the size of the batch

Comment: @Dan please, could you update the question with some piece of code or pseudo-code that shows how this is done? The current snippets give us not a clue about this process, so it is difficult to understand the actual problem